# Output value based on attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there any way to output a value based on an attribute?
I'm very new to XSLT, so please bear with me if it is obvious :)

I have an XML looking like this:

```
<Columns>
    <Column DataType="String">Id</Column>
    <Column DataType="String">FirstName</Column>
    <Column DataType="String">LastName</Column>
    <Column DataType="String">TheDescription</Column>
</Columns>
<Rows>
    <Row>
        <Value Column="Id">1</Value>
        <Value Column="FirstName">John</Value>
        <Value Column="LastName">Doe</Value>
        <Value Column="TheDescription">Some description about John Doe</Value>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Value Column="Id">2</Value>
        <Value Column="FirstName">Jane</Value>
        <Value Column="LastName">Doe</Value>
        <Value Column="TheDescription">Some description about Jane Doe</Value>
    </Row>
</Rows>
```

I've tried to do the following:

```
<xsl:template match="Template">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="loop[@name='Rows']" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="loop[@name='Rows']">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../loop[@name='Columns']/item" mode="header" />
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="row" />
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="row">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="loop[@name='Row']" />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="loop[@name='Row']">
    <xsl:param name="Column" />
    <xsl:if test="$Column = FirstName">
        <td>Output the value of FirstName here!</td>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The last 6 lines should output FirstName. How can that be done?

Comment: Your XML does not match to your XSLT at all. The XLST expect loop nodes with mane attribute.

Comment: @hr_117 something went wrong when formatting the XSLT. The first block of code have been added.

Comment: Does not really help. This code will do nothing with your XML

Comment: Well - OK. Can you put me on track, how to output the desired column, without looking at my XSLT?

Comment: What do you need to accomplish? Create a `TABLE` where each `Column` element is a `TD`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="." /></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Rows/Row">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Value">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="@Column = 'FirstName'">
                                    <b><xsl:value-of select="." /></b>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="@Column = 'LastName'">
                                    <i><xsl:value-of select="." /></i>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rubens Farias. But what i'm trying to do is actually to sort the values based on the attributes (eg. `FirstName`, `LastName`). So if the attribute is `FirstName` - make it bold and if it's `LastName` make it italic. Can it be done with `<xsl:if test="expression with attribute">` or something? I don't know how to get the attribute.

Comment: You can use `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose`; to refer to an attribute, you need to prefix it with an `@` character